# Why isn't there any option for favourite ANSWER?

Tags: discussion, answers, bookmarks

I notice that there is no option of favourite answers. What I have to do now is to favourite the question containing the answer. I think that it is a little unfair that the question SEEMS to be "taking" the credit of the answer.

So I would like to know if it is possible to introduce a "favourite answer" to math.SE.

Comment: Older related questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/favoriting-an-answer, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007/is-there-a-way-to-save-the-favorite-answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Why? Because Jeff Atwood [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/251274) to implement such a feature, despite the request having +180 score and his answer heavily downvoted. Also, because (as it seems to me) nobody at SE did anything to improve the functionality of favorites since Atwood left. Which leaves us with options:

- bookmark in a browser, or
- bookmark in some cloud-bookmarking thing (does delicious still exist? yep), or
- add the link to answer to your profile box, if you need really quick access to it from within SE.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is not possible because Jeff declined it. I would say that it is unlikely.

Comment: Has Jeff ever told us the reason for that? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @IanMateus << Considering the average stack overflow question has maybe 3 answers, tops, the distinction between "I favorite this question" and "I favorite this answer" is minimal. Allowing favoriting answers would also make the interface noisier, and implicitly encourage questions with lots of answers. This isn't going to happen, so either come to terms with the decision, or find another site on the internet that's more to your liking. >>  [Jeff being Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star#comment277614_107790)