# Is there any way to add a bookmark to any answer of a question?

Tags: support, answers, bookmarks

I basically if needed used to *follow* the question as I didn't find any way to add a bookmark to any answer like the amenity we have for a question. Does someone have any ideas regarding this?

Comment: Related older posts on this meta: [Can we have a favorite star for answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22149), [Is there a way to save the favorite answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2007), [Why isn't there any option for favourite ANSWER?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12924), [Favoriting an answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5098).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have a favorite star for answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22149/can-we-have-a-favorite-star-for-answers)

Answer (score 5):

While bookmarks indeed only work for questions, you can follow both answers and questions. By following the question, you are notified of new answers, which you could then follow as well.

An old feature request to bookmark answers has been [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/295232); there are several alternatives listing there, including using your browser's own bookmark feature.